# Zipping lists within a list in Python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, zip

I have a list of lists

```
big_list = [['a1','b1','c1'], ['a2','b2','c3'], ['a3','b3','c3']]
```

how do I zip the lists within this list?

what I want to do is `zip(list1,list2,list3)`, but do this dynamically

I believe it has to do smth with `args` and `kwargs` which I am not familiar with, any explanation is welcome

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `*args` argument expansion syntax:

```
zip(*big_list)
```

The `*` (splash) tells Python to take each element in an iterable and apply it as a separate argument to the function.

Demo:

```
>>> big_list = [['a1','b1','c1'], ['a2','b2','c3'], ['a3','b3','c3']]
>>> zip(*big_list)
[('a1', 'a2', 'a3'), ('b1', 'b2', 'b3'), ('c1', 'c3', 'c3')]
```